# How can i see the width for example on my HTML elements on the browser with my mouse?

Tags: html, css, browser

I watched this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVLmX-fx09w

and here on 12:20 - 12:25, with the mouse he can see how wide for example is the whole HTML element on the browser. How can i 'include' this feature on my browsers for example Microsoft edge or Chrome ?

Comment: Press `F12` and open _developer tool_ .

Comment: @SatoTakeru i know that i can see the width through developer tools. I want to see with mouse draggings like he ie doing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he is just taking a screenshot.
If you're on a Mac, use cmd + shift 4 and click-&-drag, it should show you pixel height + width.
I'm not too sure if the Windows operating system has this feature, but you can use 3rd party apps such as [Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/) that does the exact same.

You'd be better off inspecting elements in the Chrome Developer tools though.